# How can I deserialize any XElement into an object

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, xml-parsing

I'm looking to be able to take any XElement in code, and chuck it straight into a Razor view as a dynamic model.

How can I automatically parse the XElement into a dynamic object regardless of the contents of the XElement?

Comment: There isn't anything built in for this, you would need to write your own custom serializer.

Comment: @James I expected as much, but I'm sure someone out there has already done this; my google-fu failed me though.

Comment: I'm trying this, and coming to the conclusion that it's not been done because the answers are a) ugly and b) no more useful than XElements.

Comment: did you see my answer regarding the `ExpandoObject`? That's probably as close as you are going to get.

Comment: @James What further context would you like?

Comment: could you perhaps post some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried this. I think I understand now why there isn't widespread code to do this, and invite your comments, edits and criticisms:

```
    private dynamic LoadFromXElement(XElement source)
    {
        var name = source.Name.LocalName;
        var descendants = source.Descendants().ToList();

        dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
        var resultDict = result as IDictionary<string, object>;

        if (descendants.Count == 0)
        {
            resultDict[name] = source.Value;
            return result;
        }
        var dynamicDescendants = descendants.Select(element => LoadFromXElement(element)).ToList();

        resultDict["element"] = dynamicDescendants;

        return result;

    }
```

That said, I am already coming up with some improvements on this approach...

Comment: Wouldn't you just need the inner for loop in my example to extract all the fields from your XML into a dynamic object? It's difficult to actually answer your question specifically as you haven't provided any context.

Comment: @penguat Using [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can get the dynamic object easily `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xElem);
            dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: @James a lot of the elements I will be dealing with contain text, which wouldn't be picked up otherwise.

Comment: @L.B I like it! it'd be nice if it could be short-circuited somehow but I might end up doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 4 you could have a look at the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx).

Example from the link provided deserializes the following XML into a list of dynamic `Person` objects:

```
<Persons>
    <Person>  
        <FirstName> Dino </FirstName>
        <LastName> Esposito </LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName> John </FirstName>
        <LastName> Smith </LastName>
    </Person>  
 </Persons>
```

Parsing code:

```
public static IList<dynamic> GetExpandoFromXml(String file) 
{ 
    var persons = new List<dynamic>();

    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var nodes = from node in doc.Root.Descendants("Person")
                select node;

    foreach (var n in nodes) 
    {
        dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var child in n.Descendants()) 
        {
            var p = person as IDictionary<String, object>);
            p[child.Name] = child.Value.Trim();
        }
        persons.Add(person);
    }
    return persons;
}
```

Comment: -1 for ignoring xml attributes, loosing parent-child relationships and returning list of dynamic objects where it could be one

Comment: @L.B what are you talking about? This is an example extracted from the article I provided to demonstrate how to use the `ExpandoObject`. The OP didn't say what sort of data they are dealing with so I can't offer any sort of code as yet - your downvote is needless & unjust.

Comment: `The OP didn't say what sort of data they are dealing with so I can't offer any sort of code as yet` That you can't offer does not make it unanswerable, An XElement can be converted to a single dynamic object. See the comments of "penguat's" answer.

Comment: @L.B I am not going to *guess* at what the OP is trying to do, I have provided a perfectly valid answer for the question asked with a working *example* of how you would do it. So again, your downvote is harsh & to be honest seems petty.

Comment: James, you really don't understand? Without any sample xml, A generic code can be written that does not exclude `xml attributes`, and preserve parent-child node relationships.

Comment: @L.B The question was "*How can I automatically parse the XElement into a dynamic object regardless of the contents of the XElement*" - the example above demonstrates that, I don't really see what else you want me to do without any context, like I said before I am not going to provide code samples on assumptions. `does not exclude xml attributes` - your now assuming the OP *wants* or even *needs* to read in xml attributes and this is the point I am making, I have answered based on the information provided, I'm afraid your argument is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

try this extension

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this  XmlReader xml)
    {

        if (xml == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        // No settings need modifying here




        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xml);


    }
```

and for call

```
var obj = xElement.CreateReader().Deserialize<objectType>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not use a dynamic object, so a class would have to be created effectively specifying how the XML is to be deserialized.

Comment: Where is `settings` being used?

Answer (score -1):

Just cast it to a dynamic?

```
var xele = new XElement("foo", "bar");
    var p = (dynamic)xele;
    Console.Write(p.Name);
```

or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to have the XML serialized to a dynamic object, not the XElement object itself.